# How to pass parameters to function in decorator

Tags: python, flask, decorator

I have a decorator and want to let `newname` pass to  `protected()` and show, what should I do?

If `name='Jan'` and in decorator the `newname` equal to `Jan hello!!!` and then `newname` can be  `print(newname)` used in `protected()`

my code

---

app.py

```
@app.route('/protected')
@lookname
def protected():
    return jsonify({'message': 'This is only available for people with valid tokens!'})
```

lookname.py

```
def lookname(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        name = request.cookies.get('name')
        newname = name + ' hello!!!'
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

---

I want to like this

```
@app.route('/protected')
@lookname
def protected():
    print(newname)
    return jsonify({'message': 'This is only available for people with valid tokens!'})
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`g`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.g) to carry any bits of information bound to the request context.

```
from flask import g

def lookname(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        name = request.cookies.get('name')
        g.newname = name + ' hello!!!'
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

And then in `protected`:

```
from flask import g

@app.route('/protected')
@lookname
def protected():
    print(g.newname)
    # ...
```